# xpath check if node has not specific children

Tags: xpath

I have an HTML file like this:

```
 <tr>
   <td class= 'iconmenu' width="100%">...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class= 'iconmenu' width="100%">...</td>
   <td class= 'iconmenu'>...</td>
</tr>
```

The first element  has one child and the second has two child, the question is:

How can I check if the first element has one child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the number of child elements of the first `tr`:

```
count(/*/tr[1]/*)
```

Counting only `td` children:

```
count(/*/tr[1]/td)
```

Perform the comparison like this:

```
<xsl:if test="count(/*/tr[1]/td)=1">
```

Note the use of an absolute path (starting with `/`). You may be tempted to do `count(//tr[1]/td)`. Note that this returns the count of *all* `tds` across *every* row that is the first row in every table in the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(td)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let $s := <test><table>
<tr>
   <td class= "iconmenu" width="100%">...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="iconmenu" width="100%">...</td>
   <td class="iconmenu">...</td>
</tr>
</table></test>


return fn:count($s//table/tr[1]/td)
```

Please ref: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0015.html#c0016